# Keyboard is not Hiding

Tags: android, keyboard

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();

    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Its not working....!!!
When I Click on edittext it will open the keyboard after that when i click another button keyboard is not hiding..

Comment: probably your `EditText` is getting focus again on button click

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false)` on the `EditText`'s instance.

Example:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

**XML :**

```
android:editable="false"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
android:inputType="none"
```

Comment: Not Working...!!!

Comment: @Harshilkakadiya try adding the xml above, also what is your app's api level?